# How to validate input text length in material input?

Tags: input, dart, angular-material, angular-dart

I am developing an application using angular dart. I am using angular dart material input for getting input from user.

I have a multiline text input for which I use material input and type="text".

I have made this field "required" but the problem is when the user enters white space or enter, the "required" is gone. I need a attribute where i can specify a constraint that at least one non-white space character must be entered.

How to achieve this?

Here is my code where I have used material input:

```
<material-input
    ngControl="textAnswer" [(ngModel)]="answer" multiline
    type="text" label="Your answer" required>
</material-input>
```

Comment: `pattern=".*\S+.*"` with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#-code-lt-input-gt-code-and-code-lt-textarea-gt-code-attributes) you can use all `input` elements attribute with it.

> All of the attributes that can be used with normal `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements can be used on elements inside `<mat-form-field>` as well

So use [HTML5 `pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression) to match the custom pattern(regular expression).

```
<material-input
    ngControl="textAnswer" [(ngModel)]="answer" multiline
    pattern="[\s\S]*\S[\s\S]*"
    type="text" label="Your answer" required>
</material-input>
```

[`[\s\S]*\S[\s\S]*`](https://regex101.com/r/q3Wuk4/2) will help to match a string with at least one non-space character.

NOTE : To include all other character use `[\S\s]` since `.` doesn't include a newline character.

Comment: This is not working for multi line inputs. It is throwing required validation error even if non white space character is present and new line is pressed.

Comment: @Sabareesh :  try `pattern=".*[^ ].*"` ... (_Note : there is a space within the square bracket_)

Comment: this is not validating new line. it checks for only spaces

Comment: Working. Thank you so much. Basically, it matches all characters by [\s\S]* and a mandatory non white space character by \S, right?

Comment: @Sabareesh : yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191584/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-sabareesh).

Comment: Note this is actually using the pattern validator it is not getting passed into the input below. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/abf086dd898aa092907835d063f981df1cfe3251/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/validators.dart#L174